# Ninject, how to bind Interface with generics

Tags: generics, interface, ninject

I have a simple interface that looks like this:

```
public interface ICommandHandler<T>
{
    void Handle(T command);
}
```

Then I have several implementations of that interface, here is one example:

```
public class RegisterUserCommandHandler : ICommandHandler<RegisterUserCommand>
{
    private readonly IUserRepository _userRepository;

    public RegisterUserCommandHandler(IUserRepository userRepository)
    {
        _userRepository = userRepository;
    }

    public void Handle(RegisterUserCommand command)
    {
        var user = new User(command.UserId, command.Password);
        _userRepository.Add(user);
    }
}
```

I wan't to be able to resolve the correct implementation of the `ICommandHandler` interface like this:

```
var handler = _kernel.Get<ICommandHandler<T>>();
```

My questions is this: how do I configure the bindings with Ninject?

**UPDATE**
Maybe I figured this one out, here is my solution with the [Ninject.Extensions.Conventions](https://github.com/ninject/ninject.extensions.conventions/wiki/)

```
_kernel.Bind(x => x
                .FromAssemblyContaining<ICommandInvoker>()
                .SelectAllClasses().Excluding<IDocumentSession>()
                .BindAllInterfaces());
```

Comment: You might need this too https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups#!topic/ninject/qk1r11N7ePc

Comment: Trying to figure out this myself. Could you add how you obtained the correct handler? Your answer does not make sense